# Moving from IIS ISAPI rewrite to Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis

I've seen few people have asked this on here already, but none of the solutions provided worked for me so far.

We have always been developing for the IIS ISAPI rewrite (on Windows) and suddenly one of the clients decided to place the project on the Linux server running Apache. As a result some of the rules are no longer working.

Example of an ISAPI rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^login/?([^/]*)([^/]*)$ /login.cfm?msg=$1&$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^login.cfm$  /login/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

login.cfm is an actual existing page and not dynamically generated based on template.

Could someone help me how to translate this for the Apache mod_rewrite please? Currently the rule creates an infinitive loop and the output is:

> login/?msg=&&msg=&&msg=&&msg=&&msg=&&msg... (till the limit of the url length)

Safe to say the page is not found either so it doesn't even check whether the file with such name exists.

The page could be /login or /login/wrong so the rule should recognize both cases.

Comment: What URL do you want to show in browser and what is equivalent internal URL for that?

Comment: @anubhava browser could be either www.domain.com/login or www.domain.com/login/wrong. In either of these cases server should see login.cfm?msg=$1

Comment: Pleased you got this working. However, just for future reference, we try to discourage requests for urgency, since everyone here is a volunteer - [read more here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495). We also prefer questions to contain an attempt, rather than direct requests for code conversion - sometimes the latter can get closed as too broad. Hope that helps!

Comment: @halfer thanks for the remark. All understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /login\.cfm\?msg=([^\s&]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /login/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^login(?:/([\w-]+))?/?$ login.cfm?msg=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```